# Alternative for serialization isolation level

Tags: sql-server, deadlock, database-deadlocks

I have two store procedures . Below one Selection stored proc is reads the data and update status to 1 and then selects the data.

```
 ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SP_GetPolicyEventsOminibusbyEvents]
(
@PublishStatus int,
@TopN int
)
AS 
--SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL Serializable

BEGIN TRANSACTION POLICYEVENTS 


Declare @eventId int
Create table #tempEvents
(
    [EventID] [int]  NOT NULL,
)
Insert into #tempEvents
(
[EventID] 
)
(Select top(@TopN) [EventID]   FROM [dbo].[PolicyEventsOminibus] WITH (UPDLOCK,READPAST) WHERE [PublishStatus] = @PublishStatus)

update [PolicyEventsOminibus] set [PublishStatus]=1 where Eventid in (Select #tempEvents.eventid from #tempEvents)

Select  [PolicyEventsOminibus].* FROM [dbo].[PolicyEventsOminibus] WITH (UPDLOCK,READPAST) where Eventid IN(Select #tempEvents.eventid from #tempEvents)

drop TABLE #tempEvents
commit TRANSACTION POLICYEVENTS
```

After fetching the data we do some processing and then update the status to 2 using below stored proc.

```
     ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Update_DMVPolicyEventsOminibus]
(
@Publishstatus int,
@PrevPublishstatus int,
@LastUpdatedTimeStamp varchar(100),
@EventID int,
@RowVersion rowversion  
) 
AS
--SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL Serializable

Begin Transaction


Update PolicyEventsOminibus
SET
Publishstatus = @Publishstatus ,
LastUpdatedTimeStamp  = @LastUpdatedTimeStamp
where EventID = @EventID and [RowVersion] = @RowVersion and Publishstatus =@PrevPublishstatus
Commit Transaction
```

**But without using isolation level Serialization I am getting the dead lock as "Transaction (Process ID 61) was deadlocked on lock resources with another process and has been chosen as the deadlock victim." when running multiple sessions or Instances**

**I want to avoid Serialization in select stored procedure especially as it blocks the insertion.
I have seen other related question on stack over flow. But not helpful.**

My understanding is if we apply READPAST and UPDLOCK the rows should be blocked for selection by other thread and should not get dead lock. Please correct me if I am wrong.

I would appreciate if somebody help me to identity the alternative?.

Comment: It seems that the first procedure could be rewritten without temp table using a single `UPDATE` statement with `OUTPUT`. I'm not sure what would be the effect of `UPDLOCK, READPAST` hints.

Comment: Yes. My be we can write inner select query rather than inseting into temp and then read it from temp. I am using UPDLOCK,READPAST to lock the rows so that no other process can pick the same rows until transction completes.